# How to display all of a package's options in the body of the document?

Tags: packages, package-options

I'm currently learning Latex and using Overleaf plus documentation. Sometimes I want to quickly see what other options a package has to offer. Since Overleaf shows a PDF preview, I would like to know if there is a way to quickly list that package's options.

Basically what I'm looking for is a page like [TeX_primitives_listed_by_TeX_engine](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TeX_primitives_listed_by_TeX_engine) that shows each primitive but with a link that explains watch each one does. Like the docs for any programming language, for example.

Comment: Usually the package documentation is the easiest way to learn about package options and how to use them. You can access them online at https://texdoc.org/index.html

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's not likely that your question is unique to `overleaf`. I've edited the tags

Comment: Really, your best strategy is to read the package or class documentation. Parsing the TeX code would be quite difficult. Some use keyval syntax, some do not, and even if the TeX code is parsed and printed, it would not contain any explanation of what the various choices do.

Comment: 7 days later I gotta say. That was a good comment/answer. The best thing really is checking CTAN docs and just plain research.